# RegEx format need to display

Tags: javascript

```
Q[1-4] _ [1988-2005]
```

Hi i want above format of data it should like `"Q1 _ 1989"` how to do in javascript RegEx.

Could you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
var regex = /^Q[1-4] _ ((19(88|89|9\d))|200[0-5])$/;
```

That is, match:

```
^                  beginning of string
Q                  literal Q
[1-4]              the digits 1,2,3 or 4
 _                 a space then an underscore, then another space
(                  beginning of year group
(19(88|89|9\d))    19 followed by (88 or 89 or 9 plus any digit)
|200[0-5]          or 200 followed by 0,1,2,3,4 or 5
)                  end of year group
$                  end of string
```

Comment: I tested it before posting, and it worked for me with inputs in the format `Q1 _ 1988`, and didn't match years out of the range 1988-2005 or Q values out of the range 1-4.

Comment: suppose if i want to allow 2015 to 2020 then what is the format.suppose if i want to check more years like 2015 to 2080 then what is the solution for this thanks for the quick response

Comment: Read a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). My answer already explains (briefly) how the regex I've shown works, and once you've learnt the basics from a tutorial it's really not a huge leap from what I've shown to allowing 2015-2080.